# URL Blacklist request

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spam

Could we please blacklist www.jersey4cycling.com? I've just seen the third round of somebody spamming our site with this URL.

Spam answers (originally via 3 different accounts):

- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8780
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8779
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8778
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8750
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/revisions/8749/1
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8748
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8747
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8746
- https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8745

Comment: Note to regular users: you won't be able to see the deleted spam.

Comment: This user has no non-spam posts, has been contacted, and has not responded. I've deleted the user account.

Comment: @zenbike: I was leaving it around (suspended) so the evidence (IPs, etc) was easier to examine. Added links to all the spam posts from them instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, definitely. Blacklisted, thanks.